# Why have so many users given '1920' as the year of birth?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

When I started data mining the StackOverflow database, I found a surprising number of users had set their birthday in a way that made them 89 years old.

I [blogged about it](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/06/stackoverflow-data-mining-cleansing-the-data/) and gave a full list of the 89-year-old users, and here's a few:

- [deuseldorf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159) - Age 89
- [Coding the Wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90) - Age 89
- [Keng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/730) - Age 89
- [Will Dean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987) - Age 89
- [kokos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065) - Age 89
- [ColinYounger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1223) - Age 89
- [Lars Truijens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1242) - Age 89
- [dydx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13293) - Age 89
- [Confused Computer Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14173) - Age 89

And it's not like it was an even distribution - there were much less 80-87 year old users, and no 90 year old users.  I'm guessing these users picked a date 89 years ago (so, somewhere about 1920) that has some special significance, but I can't figure out what it might be.

What's so special about year 1920?

Comment: Looks like a totally valid question, voting to reopen.

Comment: Just to deal with 'too localized' argument: those users are probably 'older' now, and they've all, for some reason, chosen the fake birth date '1920'. This question **could** be forked to ask about the etiquette of giving fake dates in their profiles.

Comment: @ŁukaszL. indeed, they are four years older. As explained in the answers, they didn't choose random date but the minimum possible date.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because in order to become compliant with GDPR, SE has removed everything related to age and birth years from their system, and as such this question is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Actually, I suspect that the "89 year old" users are simply using the oldest date they're allowed to by the system. If you try to set your birth year before 1920, the system will return an error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> Birthday - must be after 1920/01/01

Comment: Interesting - wonder why some users are older then, like http://stackoverflow.com/users/522 and http://stackoverflow.com/users/103 ...

Comment: That is a good question. Those user IDs are fairly low, so perhaps they signed up and provided their (obviously fake) DOB before the check was in place?

Comment: i guess this means my grandfather couldn't participate in stack overflow.  this is ageism.  i'm gonna get grandpa to file suit.

Comment: Why use 1920 as the check? If people are going to add a fake date of birth then this clearly doesn't stop them and it is not impossible that it might be someone's genuine date of birth. Shouldn't the earliest date be something biologically unprecedented?

Answer (score 67):

This sounds like blatant ageism. How do you know a 90 year old man wouldn't be a useful member of the website!?

Comment: That's sexism. What about a 90 year old woman?

Comment: That's speciesism. What about sentient dogs, cats, and hemaphroditic extra-planetary aliens?

Comment: That's living-creaturism. What about rocks?

Comment: That's matter-ism.  What about clouds of energy?

Comment: That's realism. What about invisible unicorns?

Comment: That's conceptualism. What about?

Comment: 24th prime number? that's so beautiful :')

Comment: The jokes are cute, but it's a serious point.

Comment: That's... what.

Answer (score 34):

Even more aggravating is the fact that we do not allow young users on this site.

> Birthday must be before 2002/05/30

I was going to sign my 5 year old up for the site cause he was having some programming problems. I had to tell him to lie about his age. He was not too happy.

Comment: There are plenty of his peers posting on meta.

Comment: 5 year old?????

Comment: Actually, it should be 5 year young.

Comment: Exactly. I am actually currently 10, but I signed myself up as 13. Come on, can't the younger generation have something to say?

Comment: @SmallDeveloper, it could be caused by the [Children's Online Privacy Protection Rule](http://www.ftc.gov/enforcement/rules/rulemaking-regulatory-reform-proceedings/childrens-online-privacy-protection-rule):
"COPPA imposes certain requirements on operators of websites or online services directed to children under 13 years of age, and on operators of other websites or online services that have actual knowledge that they are collecting personal information online from a child under 13 years of age".

Comment: Yeah, OK, blah, blah, rules, rules, rules

Comment: @Earlz, Instead of a plain "NO", there should be [a link to a page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61770/159916) describing what must be done for the poor child below 13 to sign up without lying about his age.