# Are there statistics on user details?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious about the people using  stackoverflow, specifically age range.  Is there anywhere to get details on the statistics about the users?  Is that sort of information included in the database dump?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Public statistics](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com) are available for stackoverflow, which show age ranges, gender, etc

You could also get the age details from the [Users](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Understanding_the_StackOverflow_Database_Schema#Users_Table) table in [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/), although I do not think the [ages are accurate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2307/why-are-so-many-user-ages-89).

Comment: Is that based on the data in each user's account tab or on something more generic?

Comment: I don't think so, you would have to ask the SO team.  http://www.quantcast.com/docs/display/info/FAQ

Comment: The ages are from the user profiles. They're as accurate as you can expect from online forms.

Comment: Thanks...that was what I was looking for

Comment: I'm suspicious of the Quantcast data. I know that personally I haven't provided them most of the data they claim to know about me.