# Birthdate field in bio does not allow older than 94 years?

Tags: bug, profile-page, age

I notice that entering an old date in the "birthdate" field returns the error "Date must be later than 1920/01/01" **which is actually not true**, because you can enter a date of 1920/01/01.

Also, are the developers assuming no one on the site is older than 94? I know that SAS database dates have a range begin at 1920. Tell me they are not using SAS to power Stack Exchange.

Comment: At least you can answer part of that yourself: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network ;)

Comment: This isn't so much a bug, but by design. If you're looking for a feature request to add to, try this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66384/212780

Comment: StackExchange is full of hate. They hate fun, they hate old people, they hate young people too. Nobody under thirteen can join! They also hate transgenders, as evidenced by their hate of the hyphen site

Comment: We all know the world began January 1st 1970. Frankly I think we're already too patient with people who claim to have been born before the beginning of time

Comment: Do you know somebody on Stack Overflow older than 94 who is therefore affected by this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is me. Today is my anniversary - 100 years old.

Comment: @nicael: birth certificate (notarised) or it didn't happen.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That would be me. I feel I do not require a birth certificate, as I was born in 240 AD.