# Delete own answer bug?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, self-delete

I've just attempted to delete [an answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221571/age-restriction-for-mod-election/221578#221578) (now deleted so only seen by 10K rep users), but on the first click of the "delete" link, instead of the answer being deleted the "delete" link just changed to:

> delete(1)

And the answer was not deleted.

When I clicked  "delete(1)" the answer was then deleted as normal.

I'm sure this is a one off, and I'm not griping, just thought I'd mention it in case there's a little niggle somewhere in the code which could be ironed out.

Comment: never seen that before... did you take any screenshot?

Comment: @hacker I didn't, although there really isn't much to see. Just the answer displayed as normal with "deleted(1)". Tho I should have screenied really, slaps self a bit.

Comment: Did you merge accounts perhaps since posting that answer? Even auto merge that you didn't ask for?

Comment: @James I don't know how to reproduce... may be posting in a sandbox and deleting it..

Comment: @HackerKarma Just tried, and (as suspected) the answer was simply deleted on the first click, as per normal. I guess this one is going to be impossible to manually repro.

Comment: Maybe that was their way of saying *are you sure?* I "added this to the list of the weirdest SE bugs".

Comment: According to the post's timeline, it only recorded one deletion vote from you. I'm going to mark this as norepro. :-(

Comment: Hm, I know that this has happened to me in various cases as well, but it's largely been sporadic.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young No worries. It's not exaclty a reocurring or frequent issue. If it happens again I'll take a screen shot (and try to grab some code) Cheers