# YouTube video age restrictions bypassed

Tags: bug, videos, youtube

Looking at this question, [Is ATC communication subject to FCC profanity regulations?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/is-atc-communication-subject-to-fcc-profanity-regulations), the user is able to play the video in the post without issue, when they are signed in.

> [image: SE page with embedded video]

However, if you click on the video URL and open it in a separate tab/browser (where you have not logged into your Google account), then YouTube asks you to log in to Google to be able to watch it due to age restrictive content:

> [image: Video Restriction in YouTube]

Now the age limit for *Stack Exchange* is 13, see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195941/278543) to the question [Minimum age on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195939/minimum-age-on-stack-overflow), whereas the age limit for *Google restricted videos* appears to be 18, see [Appeal the age restriction on your video](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1153367?hl=en-GB).

So, there seems to be a discrepancy.

---

#### Reproduction of the issue

This issue is easy to verify (in Chrome):

1. Open an incognito window in Google Chrome
2. *Paste and Go* the URL: `https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/is-atc-communication-subject-to-fcc-profanity-regulations`
3. *Paste and Go* the URL: `https://youtu.be/8dLS8_xM2LI`

In fact, these steps above show that you don't even have to log in to your SE account to bypass Google's age controls.

Comment: Do age restricted videos require a login when embedded elsewhere?

Comment: So the issue is that if you embed an youtube video, youtube no longer does its age control checking. Isn't this more of a problem for YouTube then for SE?

Comment: @rene - that is a good point, presumably the answer is yes. See my comment below to Cai

Comment: @Cai - I have just embedded it here, [YouTube age restriction workaround](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2016/12/26/youtube-age-restriction-workaround/), and the same issue occurs, so it is, apparently, not restricted to only SE.

Comment: Umm, 13 is the minimum age for all of Stack Exchange as well

Comment: @PythonMaster as well as what? The question states *the age limit for Stack Exchange is 13*

Comment: @PythonMaster - Yes it is, as I have stated in my post. However, the _title of the question_ that contains the answer was specifically for Stack Overflow... even though the _answer_ was for Stack Exchange. My last edit should reflect both of these points, as I incorporated your edit, which pointed directly to the answer as well as re-instating the correct title of the post :-)

Comment: @MartinSmith - As well as Stack Overflow, which the question, to which I linked to, somewhat, confusingly refers to in its title - rather than Stack Exchange in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @zaq said, in a (now deleted) comment, Google [refuses to do anything about this](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3013):

> As per the internal team, age gating is not something that can be supported for embedded playbacks.

This becomes a problem for YouTube and Google to handle rather than something Stack Exchange. I believe we can trust each other to watch the embedded videos according to our actual [moral compasses](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=moral%20compass).