# Are users under the age of 13 now allowed?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, users, age

I was browsing Stack Overflow, and I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556133/7-year-old-programer-python-input-error), asked by [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5531336/ella-dariyanani) claiming to be under the age of 13, in this case, 7 years old. As far as I know, children under the age of 13 are [not allowed to sign up for an account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61770/how-do-i-use-stack-exchange-if-im-under-13-years-old), but upon further investigation, I discovered that the following text was underneath the user's username in their profile, specifically, the *"elementary, homeschool"* part:

[image]

This clearly isn't part of the user's username, so I'm now wondering: Are users under the age of 13 now alloed to sign up for Stack Exchange accounts, under certain restrictions?

Comment: As you can see from the ultra-mega-quick account deletion, it's not allowed since it's against USA law to let such accounts exist.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it isn't against the law.  It's just that COPPA is so onerous it's just easier to block them than to comply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nope, they're not allowed.

The "elementary, homeschool" part is not an official recognition of underaged users. They used the new feature that's part of the Stack Overflow profile for identifying your current position and company, school, or other and typed that into the box.

Comment: So, if I'll write "I am 10 years old" in my profile, it will be deleted, just like that?

Comment: ^ Yeah, that's weird. The words they've put there is not the proof they are actually 7.

Comment: Yep. We have no way of proving how old you are, and if you're *claiming* that you're underage, then we don't really have any choice but to assume that you are.

Comment: We all know @ShadowWizard is about to turn 13 so if we keep it quiet, his account may survive...

Answer (score 8):

> [image]

The thing is, one can put there whatever they want.