# It's nice to know that Stack Overflow also attracts the older demographic

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, age

Specifically, why is it that there are **[2 users older than 90](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/10380/)**:

**[svec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103)** is 110

**[Ed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522)** is 257

This seems to violate the warning that is given if you try to put in a birthdate that would make you over ~90

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>   Birthday must be after 1920/01/01

**PS:** svec has aged extremely well:

[image]

Comment: There can be only one!

Comment: svec has overflowed.

Comment: svec used an old picture of when he was 90 years old. That is why it seems he has aged extremely well. `;-)`

Comment: At least Richard Wilkins III created a new profile every 60 years or so.

Comment: I think it's a time lord thing.

Comment: Related: [Why are so many user ages “89”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2307/why-are-so-many-user-ages-89)

Comment: +1 for the question title

Comment: Hey now, the undead are people too. +1 @Peter, welcome to 3k!

Answer (score 12):

They are user numbers 103 and 522, joining SO over 2 years ago when it was still in beta and probably didn't have all the checks and balances in place.

It is otherwise a side-effect of awarding prizes to people disclosing personal information that they don't want to reveal.  That Autobiographer badge probably only really accomplished getting *less* accurate info.

Comment: What, you don't believe that I'm only 9 years old?

Comment: @Ether - Nope. A 9 year old would never ever say "I'm **only** 9"... they would only say "I'm **already** 9" ;)

Comment: @Peter, the nine year olds I know would say "but I'm *nearly* **ten**..."

Comment: @Ether, I believe you. The feline years/human years conversion always baffled me, but you seem like a trustworthy cat.

Comment: @DavidThomas all the pre-18 kids say their age trying to round up (almost 18, 17 and a half etc), and everyone else is that age right up to the minute of the time they're actually born.

Answer (score 5):

Personally i think anybody aged up to `int.Max` should be allowed without discrimination.

The site also attracts young'uns, including [some aged 10](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146015/slugster) or under. When my parents won't let me go down to the mall to hang out with all the hot girls i get on here and answer questions instead.

Comment: Hopefully no work-related questions from you!

Comment: Sure, but young people shouldn't be banned. I started using SO when I was 11...

Comment: @Andrew - don't worry, i am older than that, but i firmly believe that age is a state of mind... Age shouldn't matter on a site like this, if you've got the rep and the badge flair then you must know what you are talking about.

Comment: I'm 2147483647 years old, going on -2147483648.