# How come somebody's 257 years old?

Tags: bug, age

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [It's nice to know that Stack Overflow also attracts the older demographic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63497/its-nice-to-know-that-stack-overflow-also-attracts-the-older-demographic)

https://stackoverflow.com/users/522

Need I say more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a dupe: [It's nice to know that Stack Overflow also attracts the older demographic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63497/its-nice-to-know-that-stack-overflow-also-attracts-the-older-demographic/63504#63504)

I wonder how Ed feels now that he has hit his second byte. (2^<sup>8</sup> + 1 .....)