# What happens to posts by an underage user whose account was deleted?

Tags: support, users, deleted-accounts, age

If an underage user's account is deleted, will their posts still be there?

I know that if a normal account is deleted by the owner, their posts remain. But, is it the same for underage users?

Comment: TL;DR: since posts aren't considered private info about the user, they're not deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The posts aren’t automatically deleted. Here’s an example from Writing (where examples can easily be found by tag): [Is it ok to be 11 and be writing a book while behind on school work?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/53706/34330)

Deleting a young user’s account is different from a regular deletion, but only because of what happens on the backend: it scrubs any personal data such as email.

See also: [What are our policies regarding underage users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355419/323179)