# Can usage of the mod-agreement-policy tag trigger a moderator notification?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, notifications, moderators, announcements

When a new question is tagged [mod-agreement-policy](/questions/tagged/mod-agreement-policy) I'd like it to trigger a moderator notification.

I ask because the new moderator agreement requires:

> I will abide by all other officially announced moderator and user policies made [available to me](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mod-agreement-policies).

When a new policy is announced I'd like to be notified, without having to search MSE for it. I ask after [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355427/why-are-moderators-now-required-to-report-underage-users), as that policy adds a new requirements; but I would not know this if I didn't frequently visit MSE.

For folks without a diamond: here is a redacted screen of the last notification I had for a policy change.

[image: Image of moderator notification for the updated mod agreement policy]

Comment: ugly way to do it till then would be to use an RSS feed for the tag...

Comment: Or they could just manually trigger one each time. Hopefully there won't be all that many of these

Comment: Aren’t moderators supposed to be notified in advance of a policy like this coming into effect? That’s my understanding of what’s here: [The new moderator agreement is now live for moderators to accept across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350544/323179)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These two policies you saw were retracted because they were released without going through the policy review release process. Moving forward, all of our new moderator policies will be going through the below process to make sure that policies are reviewed and moderators have the opportunity to give feedback on them before they're active. Moderators will get an orange diamond inbox notification when this is posted to the moderator team.

Once the policy is active and announced on MSE, we'll send out another orange diamond notification so mods know it's live. For anyone else, feel free to subscribe to the RSS for the [mod-agreement-policy](/questions/tagged/mod-agreement-policy) tag to make sure you're not missing these policies when they're public.

So, considering this, your specific request is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) because we feel there will be enough notifications through this process already.

> ### Internal Review
>
> Once the policy is drafted, the first step is for the CMs to review it internally - this allows us to catch any issues within the team before showing it to external view. In some cases, reviewing with a single CM may be enough but the entire team should be aware of the policy. Other, more complicated policies, should go through our internal review process.
>
> ### Mod Council Review
>
> The second group to view the policy will be the Moderator Council.
>
> Once their review is complete, we will make any changes that are necessary or can be made - there are some things that could come up that we may not be able to agree. The goal here is to work together towards the best possible solution.
>
> ### Moderator Team Review
>
> After the feedback from the Council, we'll make a post on the Mod Team. If there are outstanding things that the Council thought should be changed, we will use the post to explain why they aren't being changed so that the mods understand the reasoning for it.
>
> Once posted on the Mod Team, we will use an orange diamond mod notification with a link to the post so that the mods are aware of the policy and can leave comments/answers.
>
> ### Public Documentation
>
> In many (most) cases, the public documentation will be a post on MSE with the [mod-agreement-policy](/questions/tagged/mod-agreement-policy) tag. The answer will be policy locked.
>
> In some cases, we may wish to write a help center article instead. In that case, we will edit the [Moderator Agreement Policies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/mod-agreement-policies) help center article to add a link to the new help center article.
>
> Once the policy is public, we will edit the Mod Team post to link to the completed policy so that mods can quickly find it from the Team and create another orange diamond notification to let the mods know that the policy is live with a link to the policy.

Hopefully that works for you, if not let us know. It's good to understand moderator workflows as we think about these things moving forward.

Comment: "*...Once the policy is active and announced on MSE, we'll send out another orange diamond notification so mods know it's live.*" - That sounds like... exactly what this was asking for? That sounds like status-completed to me, not status-declined

Comment: Yes I agree with @Mithical, I asked for a notification, even if manually, I'am happy with that, so it can be stat-completed

Comment: @yagmoth555 The request was for the usage of the tag to be the trigger and it won't be. It'll be completely manual, meaning that whoever posts the policy must do it themselves.