# Why were two policies deleted from MSE?

Tags: support, moderators, policy

Last week two policies were posted to MSE:

- [What are our policies regarding underage users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355420/508266)
- [What are our policies regarding threats of self-harm and suicide?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355422/508266)

They have now been deleted, why?

Answer (score 29):

We posted these as they were identified as lacking on an audit conducted on our policies for moderators as part of the new agreement.

However, it seems in the interest of expediency we overlooked our own promise that new policies would go through moderator council & moderator teams review before being posted live.

These policies have now been deleted and will undergo the review above to be undeleted later after that is done.

**Update:** These policies have completed the moderator reviews, and have been undeleted and revised as per feedback.

Comment: I hope you will not simply undelete, but take feedback provided through these channels seriously. Good that you pro-actively clarify what is happening though.

Comment: @Luuklag that's the idea, yes.

Comment: This looks like a good thing that shows that you are trying to follow the procedures. No problem for making a "mistake" once. I'm not a mod, but wouldn't it be potentially useful to at least have the "What to do as a mod with suicidal/self-harm users?" still available, just not marked as policy (or even explicitly marked as "NO POLICY") to allow for mods who are looking for help to at least see it as a recommendation (with the caveat of future change)?

Comment: @MEE we already had a very similar post up on the Mod Team that mods can refer to, so I think we're good there.

Comment: @MEE well - any issue with users or site governance you can't handle... You can flag, and anything we can't handle gets kicked over to the cm team so practically except for a few details it should work the same. Also smart move preempting the why was it deleted post 

Comment: Good thing for that move, as usually the staff do ping all mods when policy get posted on the mod team. If every mod know the policy before to be posted there, you, as SE, will be a lot more backed in the move. It's a win-win scenario in the end