# Is avoiding to report underage users a violation of the moderator agreement now?

Tags: discussion, moderators, legal, moderator-agreement

There is a new official policy on reporting underage users by moderators:

[What are our policies regarding underage users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355419/what-are-our-policies-regarding-underage-users).

This is posted with the [mod-agreement-policy](/questions/tagged/mod-agreement-policy) tag, so it is officially part of the moderator agreement. This is one of the new things in the changed moderator agreement, and I'm not entirely sure how this will be interpreted in practice.

The linked policy does use the imperative asking mods to report underage users, but it doesn't use stronger language like "must report" or similar. I'm not sure if this is still SE asking politely or SE requiring moderators to report underage users at a similar level as other clauses in the main moderator agreement.

The main moderator agreement is quite clear to me, it does use straightforward language and clearly spells out the obligations of a moderator. The linked policies are referenced with the following sentence there:

> I will abide by all other officially announced moderator and user policies made available to me.

So they are supposed to carry the same weight as other obligations in the main moderator agreement. But those linked policies are written in a very different way, they are much less explicit and contain much more context.

So my main question in the end is, are moderators required to report any underage user they notice, and is avoiding to report underage users you know of a violation of the moderator agreement, with all the potential consequences?

Comment: I've already asked this same question back when the policy was originally enacted, before it was recanted as it hadn't gone through moderator review: [Why are moderators now required to report underage users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355427/why-are-moderators-now-required-to-report-underage-users). It now has a staff response indicating that it was always considered an "unspoken" policy, but as the new moderator agreement requires all policies to be public and codified, it was made so.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog no, it doesn't.

Comment: I've edited the automatic text to replace it with my own text.

Comment: This question is more focused, it is asking are moderators breaking their agreement if they fail to report an underage user. @SonictheK your post is broader and filled with unnecessary details about posts being deleted “recanted” and then undeleted “enacted”. Why is that relevant?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Those have been edited out and simplified. Also, those didn't affect the central question being asked there, which was the same as the one being asked here.

Comment: We had apparently missed this question and I just came across it from being mentioned in the TL - apologies, I'll write an answer

Comment: @CesarM just in case you have also missed [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377822), raising it here, as it's no less important in my opinion. (Can't mention it in TL as I'm not a moderator.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar handling that as part of the [other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374897) on the subject. I left a comment with an update there

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The policies tagged with [mod-agreement-policy](/questions/tagged/mod-agreement-policy) are a must-enforce for moderators. They're what the "*I will abide by all other officially announced moderator and user policies [made available to me](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mod-agreement-policies).*" line is referring to.

They're considered part of the Moderator Agreement, so moderators *are* required to report underage users found both on sites where they moderate and in chat. If they claim to be underage in chat, please raise an escalation on one of their site profiles where you are a moderator. If there isn’t such a profile, we recommend flagging it for a moderator on a site where they do have a profile (though the last bit is not required).

Knowingly ignoring a claim and not reporting it would be considered a violation of the moderator agreement, with all potential consequences that it carries, yes.

Comment: Does the part about reporting underage users in chat also apply to Chat.Meta.SE and Chat.SO, even if the mod isn't a mod on Meta.SE or SO? On those servers, only mods of the respective sites have moderator privileges.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog only the servers where the mod has moderator powers