# Why has there been such a huge drop in "new visits" since May 9th, 2022, across multiple sites?

Tags: discussion, statistics, site-analytics

##### The Data:

The following graphs are from today, starting from when the public beta started, and with data points plotted "weekly" rather than "daily".

##### Quantum Computing:

[image: Data on the number of new visits plotted weekly for QuantumComputing.SE, showing a steady increase since the start of the public beta up until the last 2 data points. The last two data points show a sharp drop to about 10% of the last value before.]

##### Matter Modeling:

[image: Weekly plotted new visit data for MatterModeling.SE. Showing a steady increase over the last year with the last two data points showing a sharp decline to about 20% of the last value before.]

#### Physics:

See [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61223947#61223947), a diamond moderator confirmed that the same thing is happening at Physics.SE, without showing the graph.

##### Prior Research / Discussions About This:

- [I originally asked this on a site's own Meta](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/543/2293) and a diamond moderator was also confused, so they asked a different site's diamond moderator in chat.
- Searches on Meta.SE such as "[new visits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=new%20visits)" don't seem to show anything related.

Comment: related: [Can we have a little notice letting people know that analytics changed after May 10, 2022?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379947/997587)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Educated guess, by no means official:

> We are committing to recategorizing the Google Analytics cookie as a “Performance Cookie” by May 13, 2022.

(source: [this answer by staff member @CesarM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378440/295232) - the actual switch happened on [May 10th](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374897/why-is-the-google-analytics-cookie-defined-as-strictly-necessary-and-saved-wit/378440#comment1264074_378440))

The [site analytics](/site-analytics) are powered by Google Analytics, and if users don't accept the cookies, they don't get registered as new visits.

Comment: May 13th does seem to be when this trend started, and it's interesting to learn that **this is the number of people who did not accept the cookie!**

Comment: @user1271772 It's not that people chose not to accept them. More likely, many users took no action. With the reclassification, that cookie can only be stored once they confirm to accept it. But a lot of users who would qualify as "new visits" would be from search engines, where they might have loaded the page, looked at it, and then left without ever interacting with the dialog at all.

Comment: Even better source: this comment https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374897/why-is-the-google-analytics-cookie-defined-as-strictly-necessary-and-saved-wit/378440#comment1264074_378440

Comment: @animuson so the cookie dialogue isn't intrusive enough ;)

Comment: @Luuklag Shhh! Don't tell 'em :-D

Comment: @Luuklag Or people use adblock and filter it out.