# Can we have a little notice letting people know that analytics changed after May 10, 2022?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-analytics

One of the effects of the [recategorization of Google Analytics cookie as a “Performance Cookie”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374897/why-is-the-google-analytics-cookie-defined-as-strictly-necessary-and-saved-wit/378440#378440) was the apparent drop in visitor numbers in the [25k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) and mod analytics tools.

[image: screenshot showing drop in traffic after May]

This seems to cause some confusion in the short term, and I've seen questions around asking about it.

I wonder if there's value in sticking a little note, like "Traffic after May 10 2022 may be affected by the recategorization of Google Analytics cookies as optional" on the page itself. Not everyone's going to remember, and it feels like a logical place for someone to find this information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update the help center page on site analytics to reflect that traffic sources are not tracked for users with performance cookies disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378444/update-the-help-center-page-on-site-analytics-to-reflect-that-traffic-sources-ar)

Comment: No it doesn't. I'd like it on the page *itself* so people will find it where its needed.

Comment: I was just exploring analytics and was stumped by this drop. I asked in mod chat and was directed here. Wasn't that much bother, but would be nice to have a small note there on the page.

Comment: The effect on [english.se] is [even greater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0WGf.png).

Comment: @AndrewLeach The effect on RPG wasn't quite as bad as ELU, but [still quite dramatic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12117/site-traffic-fell-off-the-table-the-week-of-may-10-2022-what-happened).

Comment: IMHO, it's not clear whether you are claiming **1** that the cookie change reduced the number of visitor, or **2** that it didn't actually affect the number of visitors, it only reduced the number that the system records.

Comment: The latter. Hence apparent,

Answer (score 10):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

As of July 26, 2023, the page now shows the following notice on the top of the page:

> ℹ Effective May 10th 2022, the traffic data in this chart is outdated. We are working to resolve the issue. [This update was posted on July 26, 2023]

Comment: But it doesn't say what happened. We have [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391652/323179) open about how confusing this is and if it weren't for the timing of other discussions I would be confused too.

Comment: @Laurel yeah, I agree the banner is cryptic, but at least it's there now...

Answer (score 10):

**TL;DR; We have removed Universal Analytics data throughout our sites because of the inaccuracy and eventual lack of support from Google.**

A few weeks ago, we added this banner to `/site-analytics` and `/admin/analytics` about traffic data:

[image: 25k user analytics page on Stack Overflow with banner at the top in blue that reads "Effective May 10th 2022, the traffic data in this chart is outdated. We are working to resolve the issue. [This update was posted on July 26, 2023]" above graphs showing posts and votes per day for a period of time.]

We wanted to provide clarification and next steps about this banner. In the coming weeks, we are planning to remove data points that are pulling directly from Universal Analytics because [these data points will shortly be unsupported](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en).

The changes here are as follows:

- Remove the banner from the `/site-analytics`, `/site-analytics/traffic-sources`, and `/admin/analytics` pages
- Remove the following data points from pages that include data from Universal Analytics (`/site-analytics`, `/site-analytics/traffic-sources`, `/admin/analytics`, and [stackexchange.com/sites#traffic](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)):

  - Traffic
  - Visits/day
  - Number of new visits
  - Traffic sources
  - Referring sites
  - Search engines
  - Search keywords

While the traffic data on the [Stack Exchange sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) is visible to everyone, most of the above data is only available to users with the "[access to site analytics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)" privilege or site moderators. While we’re not immediately upgrading these data points at this time, we’ll be working with moderators to better understand what data has provided value and why in order to inform if and where it should be prioritized on the roadmap.

Comment: "_most of this data is only available to_" what exactly is the "this" being referred to there?

Comment: @starball I'm referring to bulleted list. Visits/day is the only traffic related data point on the all sites page that is visible to all users.

Comment: Where is the traffic data on the sites list?

Comment: @Xanne There's a column for "visits/day". That column would be removed if I'm understanding correctly.